# Лемматизация списка русских слов: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, pymorphy2

столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо провести лемматизацию  русских слов, которые записаны в list. Соответственно средствами pymorphy2 сделать это не получилось, т.к.

```
list = ['грустно', 'зависимость', 'хорошему', 'приводит', 'альтернатив']
p = morph.parse(list)
p.normal_form
```

вполне предсказуемо выводит

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-2e9098411d7d> in <module>()
      1 list = ['грустно', 'зависимость', 'хорошему', 'приводит', 'альтернатив']
----> 2 p = morph.parse(list)
      3 p.normal_form

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py in parse(self, word)
    235         res = []
    236         seen = set()
--> 237         word_lower = word.lower()
    238 
    239         for analyzer, is_terminal in self._units:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

если же преобразовать list в string например вот так:

```
" ".join(list)
```

то вся строка воспринимается как набор букв, а не слов. других способов не смог найти. У кого-нибудь есть идеи?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `morph.parse` принимает строку, а не список, а у списка нет метода `lower`.

Сам метод `morph.parse` возвращает список с результатами анализа, поэтому чтобы получить `.normal_form` нужно у одного из результатов его и запросить.

Обработайте слова в списке так:

```
# pip install pymorphy2
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

words = ['грустно', 'зависимость', 'хорошему', 'приводит', 'альтернатив']
for word in words:
    p = morph.parse(word)[0]
    print(p.normal_form)
```

Консоль:

```
грустно
зависимость
хороший
приводить
альтернатива
```

---

Чтобы увидеть все варианты `normal_form`, можно немного изменить тело цикла:

```
for word in words:
    print(word, [p.normal_form for p in morph.parse(word)])
```

Результат:

```
грустно ['грустно', 'грустный']
зависимость ['зависимость', 'зависимость']
хорошему ['хороший', 'хороший']
приводит ['приводить']
альтернатив ['альтернатива']
```